# I get a bash: export: not a valid identifier error every time I open terminal in mac

Tags: bash, terminal, pip, export, pipenv

Whenever I open my terminal, I get the following error. It started showing up when I downloaded pipenv and I do not know how to get rid of it.

```
-bash: export: `=/Users/thomasglover/.local/bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin': not a valid identifier
```

My exports module looks like this if helps:

```
thomasglover$ export
declare -x Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.8c37Yz39Hl/Render"
declare -x CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV="base"
declare -x CONDA_EXE="/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda"
declare -x CONDA_PREFIX="/opt/anaconda3"
declare -x CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER="(base) "
declare -x CONDA_PYTHON_EXE="/opt/anaconda3/bin/python"
declare -x CONDA_SHLVL="1"
declare -x HOME="/Users/thomasglover"
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LOGNAME="thomasglover"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX"
declare -x PWD="/Users/thomasglover"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Gsr8zJipG0/Listeners"
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM="Apple_Terminal"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION="421"
declare -x TERM_SESSION_ID="645B4699-537F-4E97-8583-723CB7946577"
declare -x TMPDIR="/var/folders/pt/wx3t2z5s35z864s20cpkvtkw0000gn/T/"
declare -x USER="thomasglover"
declare -x XPC_FLAGS="0x0"
declare -x XPC_SERVICE_NAME="0"
declare -x _CE_CONDA=""
declare -x _CE_M=""
(base) Thomass-MacBook-Pro-2:~ thomasglover$ export
declare -x Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.8c37Yz39Hl/Render"
declare -x CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV="base"
declare -x CONDA_EXE="/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda"
declare -x CONDA_PREFIX="/opt/anaconda3"
declare -x CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER="(base) "
declare -x CONDA_PYTHON_EXE="/opt/anaconda3/bin/python"
declare -x CONDA_SHLVL="1"
declare -x HOME="/Users/thomasglover"
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LOGNAME="thomasglover"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX"
declare -x PWD="/Users/thomasglover"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Gsr8zJipG0/Listeners"
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM="Apple_Terminal"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION="421"
declare -x TERM_SESSION_ID="645B4699-537F-4E97-8583-723CB7946577"
declare -x TMPDIR="/var/folders/pt/wx3t2z5s35z864s20cpkvtkw0000gn/T/"
declare -x USER="thomasglover"
declare -x XPC_FLAGS="0x0"
declare -x XPC_SERVICE_NAME="0"
declare -x _CE_CONDA=""
declare -x _CE_M=""
```

I think it something is wrong with the export PATH because I do not have a folder called texbin in ~/Library/TeX so any help fixing this would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like `PATH` is exported somewhere with an extra blank, like `export PATH =/Users/...` instead of `export PATH=/Users/...` – that'd be in `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` or another startup file.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thank you so much this fixed it!